# Webpack: is that possible to hide source map only in production?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I want to debug my react app locally in the browser, 
but i set devtool property to hidden-source-map in webpack.config.js file in order to hide my source code in production.
Is there any possibility to debug locally without exposing my source map to production?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable source-map on production, but host it in a server that only allows request from whitelisted IPs. If a request came from a non-whitelisted IP, you can just return error 403 or 404.

Let's say you are uploading your source maps to amazon s3:

```
// we use webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin for more flexible setups. Set the 'devtool' option to 'false' when you are doing this.
plugins: [
   new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].js.map',
      // this is a s3 private bucket that is only accessible via whitelisted IPs
      // regular user will not be able to access the bucket
      append: `\n//# sourceMappingURL=https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sources-maps/[url]`,
      ...options,
    }),

    // other plugins.
  ]
```

Your generated JS will still have the magic comment at the end of the file:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sources-maps/main.js.map
```

But browser devtools can only download the source map if it is accessing it from a whitelisted IP, such as your office network, a company VPN, etc.

Another approach is you can just set the `sourceMappingURL` to `localhost`. With this approach, you should have all the `*.map` files available locally on your machine. When you want to debug production code, simply start a static server (e. g.: [ecstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecstatic)) locally to serve the source maps. This way, you can be sure only you can access the source maps. But, it requires manual work to download and serve the source maps locally.

Comment: Could someone viewing your website also start their own localhost server to get access to the source maps?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the environment variable for this. It would be something like this:

```
devtool: process.env.SOURCE_MAP ? 'inline-source-map' : 'hidden-source-map',
```

Then you could run tests like this for example:

```
SOURCE_MAP=true yarn test (just an example)
```

You should checkout this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv. It's possible to create .env files and use the configuration for different flows, like test and build, so you don't have to specify env variables manually, before running the command.

If you don't want to use the environment variables, you could create separate webpack config files, maybe one that has all the common stuff between production and test environments and then more specific configs that extend the common config (one for test env with source maps enabled and one for production with source maps disabled).

Comment: thanks, can be also added in `package.json`  `{"scripts":{"test": "SOURCE_MAP=true jest"}}`